# How to convert an output cell in a text cell without having " " in the text?

Tags: output-formatting, text, output

This is part of my code:

```
Grid[{{"Número de indivíduos", "Máximo", "Mínimo", "Mediana", "Média", "Desvio Padrão"}},
Dividers -> Center] // TextCell // CellPrint
```

And the result that a I get is this:

"Número de indivíduos" | "Máximo" | "Mínimo" | "Mediana" | "Média" | "Desvio Padrão"

But I want to get this result without the quotation marks, how can I do this?

Comment: Why are you using CellPrint?

Comment: @CarlWoll Just to add the cell that I want (with the output) in my notebook.

Comment: Try eliminating CellPrint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what controls whether a string shows quotes or not is the [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) option [`ShowStringCharacters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowStringCharacters). For output cells, this option is set to [`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False):

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Output", ShowStringCharacters}]
```

> False

Hence, output cells won't show quotes:

```
Grid[
    {{"Número de indivíduos", "Máximo", "Mínimo", "Mediana", "Média", "Desvio Padrão"}},
    Dividers -> Center
] // TextCell
```

[image]

If you insist on using [`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint) as well:

```
Grid[
    {{"Número de indivíduos", "Máximo", "Mínimo", "Mediana", "Média", "Desvio Padrão"}},
    Dividers -> Center
] // TextCell //CellPrint
```

[image: "Número de indivíduos" "Máximo" "Mínimo" "Mediana" "Média" "Desvio Padrão"]

then you create the following [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) object (you can see this by using `Cell | Show Expression` from the menu):

> Cell[BoxData[
> TagBox[GridBox[{
> {""<N[UAcute]mero de indiv[IAcute]duos>"", ""<M[AAcute]ximo>"",
> ""<M[IAcute]nimo>"", ""<Mediana>"", ""<M[EAcute]dia>"",
> ""<Desvio Padr[ATilde]o>""}
> },
> AutoDelete->False,
> GridBoxDividers->{"Columns" -> {False, {True}, False}, "Rows" -> {False, {True}, False}},
> GridBoxItemSize->{"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}],
> "Grid"]],
> GeneratedCell->True,
> CellAutoOverwrite->True,
> CellChangeTimes->{3.806851714647841*^9}]

Notice that this cell does not have a type (e.g., "Output") as the second argument, as the second argument is `GeneratedCell -> True`. So, the value of the option is the default:

```
CurrentValue[ShowStringCharacters]
```

> True

This is why adding [`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint) (which is completely unnecessary) shows the quotes. If you really must use [`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint), then you could change your [`TextCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextCell) to specify this option:

```
TextCell[
    Grid[
        {{"Número de indivíduos", "Máximo", "Mínimo", "Mediana", "Média", "Desvio Padrão"}},
        Dividers -> Center
    ],
    ShowStringCharacters->False
] //CellPrint
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Output with "Print" styling

Grid[{{
"Text 1",
Style["Text 2", RGBColor[0.8, 0.35, 0], Bold,
FontFamily -> "Franklin Gothic", FontSize -> 17],
"Text 3",
Style["Text 4", RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0.5],
FontFamily -> "Garamond" FontSize -> 20]
}}, Dividers -> All] // Print

Comment: The list elements are already strings, there is no need for `ToString`. The problem is the `CellPrint`.